# Blazor: Route with parameter is not resolved

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have this very simple page:

```
@page "/somepage/{id}"

@namespace My.BlazorApp.Pages

<h1>This would be page @Id</h1>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following code in my `NavMenu.razor`:

```
@foreach(var sp in ViewModel.SubPageLinks) {
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@sp.Path">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> @sp.Title
        </NavLink>
    </li>
}
```

`@sp.Path` generates `somepage/0`, `somepage/1` etc.

But when I execute the application, I get "Sorry, there is nothing at this address".

What am I missing?

Comment: you miss the leading / in your @sp.Path

Comment: No, the leading slash missing is correct. The example which is generated when creating a new Blazor app omits it too. The problem was totally different and I solved it. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It had to do with the `.csproj` file.

Searching on the net revealed [this issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20786), so I made a very simple example to reproduce it, to have that issue reopened. I just created the basic example Blazor app and added a very simple page which just displays "Foo".

When I ran that, I, too, got "Sory, there's nothing at this address".

Then I went into the `.csproj` and I found the following:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Pages\SomeOtherPage.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Pages\SomeOtherPage.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I removed this, it started to work. Plus, as @inktkiller states, I forgot to add the `:long` type definition which first caused an exception to be thrown when opening the page.

The explanation is: I am creating my Razor pages as Text files and rename them afterwards, because when I am using the Razor page wizard, my Visual Studio still generates the old `cshtml` files. And text files get added to the `csproj` in that strange manner.

Comment: But it still issues the message "Sorry, there's nothing at this address.", when I type a url like this: "https://localhost:44329/somepage"

Comment: It had solved one problem but introduced another one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify `:long` in your route parameter.

```
@page "/somepage/{id:long}"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraints

Comment: This is another issue, it is correct, but the problem was different. I am currently writing the solution.